# Postgresql and Python : Selecting data (datetime) from SQL

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm making Car parking system, and I have some difficulities with SQL database.
I'm selecting data from SQL database, but I need to get the time correctly that I could use it for further calculations. So for example I need to get the time that was inserted to database as `VARCHAR`, maybe the bad thing is that I needed to use other method as `TIME`, but that's not the case. The thing I need is to use this line `Started_Parking = row [3]`. This should get the time from database and after that, I should be able to see the time difference from the start when car was registered and current time. By doing that I should be able to calculate the sum which the "User" should pay for parking.
So by short I just need to somehow get the time from database and use it for calculations. Here's my code, I also get errors when compiling :

> Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL unsupported operand type(s)
>   for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'

```
try:
 connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                                  password="Dziugas420",
                                  host="127.0.0.1",
                                  port="5432",
                                  database="postgres")
   cursor = connection.cursor()
   postgreSQL_select_Query = "select * from vartotojai WHERE carnum=('%s')" % car_numb
   cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query) # PALEIST KOMANDA
   vartotoju_data = cursor.fetchall()  # READ DATA

   print("          CAR DETAILS: ")
   for row in vartotoju_data:
       print("Current ID: ", row[0])
       print("Car Number: ", row[1])
       print("Parked on: ", row[3], "\n")
       Pay_Time = datetime.datetime.now()
       Started_Parking = row [3] 
       Prastovetas_Laikas = Pay_Time - Started_Parking 
       print(Prastovetas_Laikas)
       # NOW LET'S CHECK IF THE TIME DIFFERENCE IS WORKING, LET'S SEE THE DIFFERENCE AFTER 20SECS. 
       time.sleep(20)
       Pay_Time2 = datetime.datetime.now()
       Prastovetas_Laikas2 = Pay_Time2 - Started_Parking 
       print(Prastovetas_Laikas2)`
```

**EDIT

Here's the code I use to import this time into database:

```
Car_Reg_Time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
postgres_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO vartotojai (CARNUM, TIME, LAIKAS) VALUES (%s,%s, %s)"""
record_to_insert = (car_numb, Reg_Tikslus_Laikas, Car_Reg_Time)
```

And here's the table of my database:
[image: DATABASE]

! laikas in database is when car was registered, the time in database is the time when the injection was made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Prastovetas_Laikas = Pay_Time - Started_Parking
```

will not work

since `Pay_Time` is `datetime.datetime` and `Started_Parking` is `str`

you need to try to use `datetime.strptime()` to convert `Started_Parking` to correct `type`

and you want to store them as `str` in your `DB` using `str(mydate)`

Comment: Hey, please take a look at the post again, I added some details.

Comment: Reg_Tikslus_Laikas is the time not when car registration was made, but when the import to sql were.

Comment: `Reg_Tikslus_Laikas = datetime.datetime.now()`

Comment: you need to pass all of your time to str before sending to DB

Comment: (%s,%s, %s) means strings

Comment: But another question, after doing that will I be able to select it later and do the math with it like this: 

`park_end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    Park_time = park_end_time - reg_time
    print("Parking time: {}".format(Park_time))
    print(reg_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
    print(park_end_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))`

Comment: no then you need to convert the time from string to datetime as I wrote in the answer, sorry if you mean that i could not read the code in your comment

Comment: Hmm, so I need to do something like this before importing to db? :
`Car_Registration_Time = datetime.datetime.now()
 str(Car_Registration_Time)`
And just then do the importation?

Comment: And with `datetime.strptime()` I should change it then ? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199013/discussion-between-dzitc-and-linpy).